# ERROR in src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts(17,8): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, ionic

Estou criando um app com ionic para um projeto e preciso integrar um mapa, além da funcionalidade de camera e galeria que deverá salvar a imagem e a geolocalização do usuário.

Estou com um problema no momento de rodar o código. Ele inicia e da o seguinte erro no console: ERROR in src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts(17,8): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Tab1Page'.
src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts(17,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.

O mais doido é que se eu altero qualquer coisa no código e mando compilar pelo Live Reloading, o código funciona.

Segue o código da minha página e do meu typescript:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
/**import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';*/

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor() {
  }

 ionViewDidEnter(){
  //Set latitude and longitude of some place
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: { lat: -34.9011, lng: -56.1645 },
   zoom: 15,
   /** streetViewControl: false, */
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      scaleControl: true,
      zoomControl: true,
  });
 }

 /**tryGeolocation(){
   this.clearMarkers();
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
     let pos = {
       lat: resp.coords.latitude,
       lng: resp.coords.longitude
     };
     let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: pos,
       map: this.map,
       title: 'I am here!'
     });
     this.markers.push(marker);
     this.map.setCenter(pos);
   }).catch((error) => {
     console.log('Error getting location', error);
   });
 } */
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      SEMEC <img id='logo' src="../assets/img/logo-prefeitura.png">
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div id='map' #map></div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: isso ta acontecendo porque voce nao importou o modulo que faz referencia a class que contem o nome google

Comment: voce não declarou a propriedade map no seu componente